# Swift: check customview conforms to protocol

Tags: swift, uiview, swift-protocols, custom-view

I have some custom views, that conforms to a protocol:

```
class CustomView1: UIView, MyProtocol {
    ...
}


class CustomView2: UIView, MyProtocol {
    ...
}
```

Then later, I want to check a view is my custom view or not by check if view conforms to my protocol, but it's not work:

```
let v = view.viewWithTag(1000)

if let _ = v as? MyProtocol {
    print("this is my custom view")
}

if v.self is MyProtocol.Type {
    print("this is my custom view")
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting a view in `v` which is an instance of CustomView1 or CustomView2?

Comment: Can't you check the instance of your delegate variable and see which class's instance is that ?

Answer (score 0):

Everything fine in code, i think you are getting nil in **let v = view.viewWithTag(1000)**

I have checked your code in playground, it works fine.
[image]